# How to do runtime type checking conditionally for conditional types

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Typescript has [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). But when I try to use the generic type associated property at runtime to branch some handling logic, I got following type errors. I'm wondering how can I get right type inference based on the type of `multiple` property?

```js
type Value<T> = T extends undefined | false ? number : Array<number>

interface Props<T> {
    multiple: T
    onChange: (value: Value<T>) => void
}

function foo<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    if (props.multiple) {
        props.onChange([1, 2]) // Error: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Value<T>'.
    } else {
        props.onChange(1) // Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Value<T>'.
    }
}
```

BTW there are no errors when I specify `false` for T

```js
function bar(props: Props<false>) {
    props.onChange(1)
}
```

Comment: [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Comment: Generic conditional types are very hard to work with.  TypeScript does not narrow or re-constrain generic type parameters via control flow analysis.  The check `if (props.multiple) {}` can have an effect on `props`, but it does *nothing* to `T`. This has led to various GitHub issue suggestions like [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) but so far nothing it in place to deal with it.

Comment: You can either keep using generic conditionals but give up on safety inside the function by asserting like [this](//tsplay.dev/w1pjAW), or you can give up on generic conditionals and get safety with discriminated unions like [this](//tsplay.dev/WKR4pm).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please notify me by mentioning @jcalz if you comment)

Comment: @jcalz The **Discriminated Unions** suits my use case very well. And an answer is welcome to end this question for good. Also thanks to caTS.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters are hard to work with.  The compiler does perform any [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) on generic type parameters themselves, so checking `props.multiple` will have no effect on `T`.  Essentially `Value<T>` is opaque to the compiler inside the implementation of `foo()`.  There are multiple open GitHub issues asking for something better here, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For now, though, you will need to either give up on compiler-verified type safety or on generic conditional types.

---

If you wanted to keep generic conditional types you could use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the errors.  You're just *telling* the compiler that `props` has a certain type.  It could look like this:

```
function foo<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    if (props.multiple) {
        const _props = props as Props<true> // assert here
        _props.onChange([1, 2]) // okay
    } else {
        const _props = props as Props<undefined | false> // assert here
        _props.onChange(1) // okay
    }
}
```

This is fine, but you are responsible for type safety here. You could have easily swapped things (say by changing `if (props.multiple)` to `if (!props.multiple)`) and the compiler would not have noticed or complained:

```
function badFoo<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    if (!props.multiple) {
        const _props = props as Props<true>
        _props.onChange([1, 2]) // okay!
    } else {
        const _props = props as Props<undefined | false>
        _props.onChange(1) // okay!
    }
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you don't care about generic conditional types, you could instead use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), which has the exact behavior you're looking for.  If you have a value of a discriminated union type, checking the *discriminant* property will narrow the whole value.

It could look like this:

```
type Props = {
    multiple?: undefined | false;
    onChange: (value: number) => void
} | {
    multiple: true;
    onChange: (value: Array<number>) => void
}

function foo(props: Props) {
    if (props.multiple) {
        props.onChange([1, 2]) // okay
    } else {
        props.onChange(1) // okay
    }
}
```

Here `Props` is now a discriminated union, where `multiple` is the discriminant property.  It's either `true` or `false | undefined`.  And when you check `prop.multiple`, the compiler narrows `props` accordingly.

That means the compiler will notice and complain if you perform the wrong check:

```
function badFoo(props: Props) {
    if (!props.multiple) {
        props.onChange([1, 2]) // error!
    } else {
        props.onChange(1) // error!
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBpCEYBUCeMCWwA5lAOJ4BuEAqjAMogBmEALtkgN4BQSPSrMyAGogANgFcIAHkwA+JAF4kmJBAAezCMAAmUJGO0QGBCFqQAfJA1FRkAfiTAxYAEYQATkgBcSAIJu3INiSji7uMpzcvAQablaISAAKbgD2MFDScly82UhgYiLMeDAiEN6YkTlIycAAwgAWIESlSAAU5KIS3sLiUrIAlApy5Ml4WhVIAL4R2Qz68IXVlsnJGS0wKWneSanp-Rzj2XgMres7AHR5BUUlA1mVOfDVUMxIAPqnaQpIH7oguttpSTMNwScL3HLvDZQM7VeqNQgQFoAbQAjAAaJAAJgAugMAPR4qoAa0CB14ExUIhs+3B2UewGebx+X2Zf0SUMk+i0hmMpgsVipEDBtJ4kPOsIaTRaKPxhOSJOwZJ4U2yU3Gs2A8zwi2cIC0ADFlqsflsOXs7pUjq0AIQ-C75QrFCC3JUPJ4vMWfRSs-4c4Gg13ZT3QiXwxGojE42XEwLW10UiCCmkipD0xnBllQpBsgHpLk84AmcyWaxCwO8YMw2qShHS6Py2Px8ZTKagSCwBDIMiUGg4fBEKBoDD0JisZM8fjIXNfC05S6Okq2bz5oyFvklwUAbldoaa3jaHWaIVcbgG8iGIzGquLs+y8+uzX9EG34N3CP37R63j8ASCx7CZ4XqMzbTLwGpaosDDLGsUKmjsLrglaMHnPeToISmdpvuG6JYriSAEjGirggmSa3vcmHVmGdb4XKCpNqqoE8OBCzAEguoGtBJrsvB445EhtpQvaVxobx4IUXCUoRrh0buCkbhxsRlLUmRlTiTWiIyjRKj+Mk8n0eSnATEAA)